# Unity и тип возвращаемого значения

Tags: unity3d

Сегодня я впервые для себя обнаружил особенность в работе с кнопками в Unity - на кнопку нельзя поместить функцию с возвращаемым значением. Например:

```
public int WoodCounter()
{
/* Какой-то код */
   return Wood;
}
```

Данный метод не будет виден в списке OnClick(). Только `Void`.
Можете объяснить мне причину данного явления?

Comment: ну а чисто логически..что вам должна вернуть "кнопка"?? даже если взять `WF` - то там тоже у кнопок `void`. потому что эта функция - подписка события на кнопку. В ней вы можете вызвать уже функцию, которая вам что-то вернет.

Comment: я даже больше скажу, обратное тоже верно, нельзя подписать на событие со строковым параметром обработчик без него. Юнити не настолько умна, чтобы понять, что параметр не используется, она просто проверяет сигнатуры функций на точное соответствие событию. Но при этом можно подписать на void событие вызов обработчика с параметром, и указать его значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Помещение функции на кнопку" - это подписка метода на событие нажатия кнопки. Когда кнопка будет нажата все подписчики будут вызваны.

То, какой именно метод можно подписать на то или иное событие зависит от сигнатуры делегата, который используется для определения события. `onClick` у кнопок - это `UnityAction`. Т.е. тип делегата без параметров, который не возвращает никаких значений. Другими словами, если вы создадите метод:

```
public void WoodCounter(int count) { }
```

Его вы тоже не сможете выбрать, т.к. он не соответствует сигнатуре - UnityAction.

Ну и как вам уже верно сказали в комментарии, какой смысл возвращать какое-то значение в кнопку? Возможно, вы просто не так пытаетесь решить стоящую перед вами задачу.

По собственному опыту могу сказать одно - лучше никогда не использовать назначение калбэков через инспектор. Дело в том, что подобный вызов практически невозможно отследить из кода и в некоторых случая вы будете очень долго искать откуда же он постоянно происходит.

Так же существует не очевидная особенность - если вы назначите в `OnClick` вызов метода, а потом сделаете метод приватным - вызов не сбросится и всё равно будет происходить несмотря на то, что метод больше не публичный.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Я сделал так, как было озвучено выше - создал void, который вызывает метод с возвращаемым значением.